# How to execute a JS statement multiple time in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I write this in JavaScript statement in browser console

```
inbreedingInvite('74011','107433','');
```

and hit enter it sends an invite to user number 107433 to join group id 74011. If i want to invite another user I have to do it manually by changing user number.

Can anyone help me by telling how this can be automated, till now **I have got this**:

```
(function myLoop (i) {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
      console.log("inbreedingInvite('74011','" + i + "','');");  //  your code here
      if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
   }, 1000)
})(10);
```

but with this code it only output the statement in the console, doesn't actually executes it on the webpage

Comment: Maybe don't send it to the console?  ;-)

Comment: Just replace this: `console.log("inbreedingInvite('74011','" + i + "','');"); `, with this: `inbreedingInvite('74011','" + i + "','');`

Comment: @Hackerman It's just `inbreedingInvite('74011', i,'');`

Comment: Sometimes you need to let them think :)

Comment: @Hackerman You're being a bit hypocritical don't you think? If you're going to tell them what to do, at least be correct.

Comment: @4castle...yes I am...but not in a evil way...the solution to this problem is so trivial that I prefer to post a comment instead of an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is correct up top (comments). Perhaps it will help to see it as a full code block:

```
(function myLoop (i) {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
      inbreedingInvite('74011',i,'');
      if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
   }, 1000)
})(10);
```

Comment: `inbreedingInvite('74011',i,'');` I guess.

Comment: Thanks gibberish the solution worked, but I think @Alex code is much simpler to understand for beginners like me. Thanks both of you.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks, appreciate the heads up. As you probably guessed, I didn't look closely at that line after stripping out the `console.log` fn. *Looked through some of your other answers, very good.*